# Set specific node id's when importing data into drupal 7

Tags: sql, drupal, import

I'm using the feeds module to import my existing data into Drupal 7 and it works great but I have one issue with the nids it generates.

I want these to match my existing site id's then I can have a nice clean transition between old and new keeping even the same urls.

Two approaches here;
1. Somehow assign these nid's as part of the import.
2. Renumber the nid's after import.

I can't find any module or other code in google to do either so looks like I will have to hack something together myself... has anyone done this before?

-

Could it be as simple as updating all these?

`SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name =  'nid'`

```
comment
history
location_instance
node
node_access
node_comment_statistics
node_counter
node_revision
search_node_links
taxonomy_index
```

edit: and these...

`SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name =  'entity_id'`

```
feeds_item
field_data_body
field_data_comment_body
field_data_field_address
field_data_field_image
field_data_field_state
field_data_field_tags
field_data_field_type
field_data_field_website
field_revision_body
field_revision_comment_body
field_revision_field_address
field_revision_field_image
field_revision_field_state
field_revision_field_tags
field_revision_field_type
field_revision_field_website
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did in the end...

It *seems* to all be working correctly, but please be very carefully and make a backup (like I did) before doing anything like this.

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');

global $database, $tables, $prefix;
$database = // your database

$prefix = 'drupal_';

$tables = array (
'comment'                 => 'nid',
'history'                 => 'nid',
'location_instance'       => 'nid',
'node'                    => 'nid',
'node_access'             => 'nid',
'node_comment_statistics' => 'nid',
'node_counter'            => 'nid',
'node_revision'           => 'nid',
'search_node_links'       => 'nid',
'taxonomy_index'          => 'nid',
'feeds_item'                   => 'entity_id',
'field_data_body'              => 'entity_id',
'field_data_comment_body'      => 'entity_id',
'field_data_field_address'     => 'entity_id',
'field_data_field_image'       => 'entity_id',
'field_data_field_state'       => 'entity_id',
'field_data_field_tags'        => 'entity_id',
'field_data_field_type'        => 'entity_id',
'field_data_field_website'     => 'entity_id',
'field_revision_body'          => 'entity_id',
'field_revision_comment_body'  => 'entity_id',
'field_revision_field_address' => 'entity_id',
'field_revision_field_image'   => 'entity_id',
'field_revision_field_state'   => 'entity_id',
'field_revision_field_tags'    => 'entity_id',
'field_revision_field_type'    => 'entity_id',
'field_revision_field_website' => 'entity_id'
    );

// Move all nids +10000 (out of the way)

$query = "SELECT nid FROM {$prefix}node WHERE nid < 10000 ORDER BY nid";
echo "$query\n";
$result = $database->query($query);
while($data = $result->fetchRow()) {
    echo "Processing nid: {$data['nid']}\n";
    changeNodeId($data['nid'], $data['nid'] + 10000);
}

// Move all nids to match guids
// (I originally imported through the feeds module, so used the guids to reorder here, but you can use your own logic as required...)

$query = "SELECT guid, entity_id FROM {$prefix}feeds_item WHERE guid <> entity_id ORDER BY ABS(guid)";
echo "$query\n";
$result = $database->query($query);
while($data = $result->fetchRow()) {
    echo "Processing guid: {$data['guid']} (nid: {$data['entity_id']})\n";
    changeNodeId($data['entity_id'], $data['guid']);
}

function changeNodeId($old, $new)
{
    global $database, $tables, $prefix;

    echo "Updating nid: {$old} -> {$new}\n";

    // Check new doesn't already exist
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$prefix}node WHERE nid={$new}";
    $result = $database->query($query);
    if ($result->fetchRow()) {
        echo "Error nid: {$new} already exists!\n"; 
        return;
    }

    foreach ($tables as $table => $column)
    {
        $query = "UPDATE {$prefix}{$table} SET {$column} = {$new} WHERE {$column} = {$old}";
        echo "$query\n";
        $database->query($query);
    }
}
```

Notes.

1. The tables listed above worked for me, it will almost definitely be different for you depending on what modules you have installed.
2. This will break your menus and any URL aliases you have set, so you have to go through manually afterwards and fix these up, not a major though.
3. Also good idea to reset your auto increment id on the node table. `ALTER TABLE node AUTO_INCREMENT = X` where X is 1 greater than the highest nid.

Answer (score 0):

If your source contains the original nids, you can just set a mapping in your feed importer to assign the nid. This way there should be no reason to manipulate the db subsequent to the import process, as each node will simply be assigned the same nid.

Obviously this may break if you have existing nodes in your site with the same nids.